# I am not able to create the pods with the below yaml query

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLables:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: bginx:1.7.9
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

error is:

```
error validating "app.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.selector): unknown field "matchLables" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec];
```

Comment: Voting to closing under the official reason of "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in `matchLables`, it should be `matchLabels`. Additionally, you have the wrong indentation of `spec.template.spec` and of its content.

Something like the following example should work:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: bginx:1.7.9
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to run the query..:)

Comment: @SubhajitDas that's great! If this answer completely solve your problem, you could accept the answer as correct.